# Slighly alter method by passing function to class constructor in Python

Tags: python

I'm writing a class which needs to use slightly different code depending on the instance.

I could achieve this through inheritance, but I wondered whether it would would be simpler to do this by passing a function to constructor when an instance is instantiated.

I'm thinking something like this:

```
class myClass():

    def __init__(self, fn):
        self.myProperty = 1
        self.instanceSpecificFunction = fn

    def myMethod(self):

        #Do things here that are common to all instances of class

        #[common code would be here]

        #But then run some code that is specific to this instance of the class
        self.instanceSpecificFunction(self)

def functionThatsSpecificToThisInstance(self):

    #In general, this code would want 
    #to be different if we instantiated a different instance

    self.myProperty = 3

myInstance = myClass(functionThatsSpecificToThisInstance)  

myInstance.myMethod()
```

Is this a terrible idea?  Does this kind of design pattern have a name?  If so is there a 'best' way to this?

Thanks very much,

Robin

Comment: Probably you're looking for a factory pattern?

Comment: What you do is known as [Dependency Inversion](http://www.oodesign.com/dependency-inversion-principle.html) and there is nothing terrible about it.

Comment: Not a terrible idea. Composing like this instead of inheritance allows you to apply various sorts of strategy patterns as you suggested. I agree with @PauloBu though, a factory pattern will makes things cleaner and easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I don't like the idea much.

First of all, you'll have random functions not belonging to any class in particular but that actually use `self` as arguments (although `self` is just a normal function argument, that's something in the code that doesn't *smell very good*).

Having functions wandering around in a module usually makes me uncomfortable, unless the module is just a *helper module* filled only with *helper functions*. But mixing classes and functions and these functions actually performing some work on classes' instances is kind of messy from my point of view.

Inheritance looks great here. Just redefine a different constructor for every class that needs it and, when other developers see the code they will have a better idea of what's going on. At the end of the day you need to code the logic for those functions, so why not just code it *inside the classes their instances represent*.

Also, you may want to take a look to the [*Factory Pattern*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). It is a *creational pattern* that might fill your needs. The idea you have makes sense, but the implementation is rather messy. By following a *pattern* you make sure to take the rights step to create nice code, understandable and reusable. Take also a look at several [*creational patterns*](http://www.oodesign.com/creational-patterns/), maybe one of them is what you're looking for.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks.  I also felt a bit uncomfortable with the random functions floating about with `self` as an argument.  I'm having a look at the factory pattern now.

Comment: @RobinL I also edited to provide a link to other _creational patterns_ that is what your looking for :) Good luck!