# How do I pass functions into a class to be set as class variables? Am getting 'is not callable' error

Tags: python, class, variables, callback

I am trying to wrap a listener object that takes callback functions with my own object that will check some conditions and call the passed-in callback functions depending on the conditions. Does python not allow functions to be passed into classes and set as class variables?

This is what I'd like to do, but am receiving a not-callable error:

```
class Wrapper:
  def __init__(fun1, fun2):
    self.fun1 = fun1
    self.fun2 = fun2
    self.listener = None

  def _fun1:
    if condition1:
      self.fun1()

  def _fun2:
    if condition2:
      self.fun2()

  def GetListener():
    return module.Listener(callback1=self._fun1, callback2=self._fun2)
```

I understand that python isn't seeing the class variables as functions, but how else would I wrap callback functions? I know I'd be able to do this in other programming languages.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: This isnt even valid python, please mae a minimum reproducable example

Comment: Take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21972606/6809926 Really similar of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Fix your code. You have to add `self` to the first parameter of all member functions (including __init__, that probably the reason, because you are trying to call `self()`). Then it may start working automagically.

Comment: @AskoldIlvento Without `self` in the parameter list, `self.fun1 = fun1` would raise a `NameError`, rather than being equivalent to `self.fun1 = self`.

Comment: @ChrisDoyle The exact code isn't the issue, it's the concept I'm asking about: how do I intercept and wrap callbacks in Python? This was my general approach, but it seems that Python doesn't allow class variables to be set as functions passed in as parameters. So how would I go about this problem? Thanks.

Comment: @CalebBolton yes it does. If it *seems* that way to you then the *code is in fact the issue*. Don't provide the **exact** code, but you have to provide a [mcve].